# How to get rid of extra breadcrumbs on thumbs pages?

Tags: jquery, removechild, targeting

I was wondering if someone might have some insight in removing extra "breadcrumbs" that are the result of actually removing the links in which they would be between. For instance, checkout this page: https://www.shoes.com/elevtd-collection.htm

There exists an issue in which our breadcrumb trail is too long, and does not drive back to a "collections" landing page that we want users to be driven to from the collections thumb pages & vice versa. There are a few different cases where I am removing these extra links, but at a basic setup it looks like this:

```js
$(".breadcrumbs a:eq(1)").css({"display": "none", "visibility":""});
$(".breadcrumbs a:eq(2)").css({"display": "none", "visibility":""});
```

This removes the required links but leaves us with instances of ">>". I want to remove the extra ">". Any and all input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: ...and you can't do this at source - where the breadcrumb is actually generated?

Answer (score 0):

.breadcrumbs {font-size: 0;}
.breadcrumbs a {font-size: 12px;}

Comment: can I use this logic and target the breadcrumbs I want to be {font-size: 0;}?    .breadcrumbs eq(indexNumber)

Comment: Yes.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(n), or &:fisrt-child, &:last-child